Cómo convertir select sentencia preparada a vista mysql
tengo una tabla con los siguientes registros y estructura

y tengo la siguiente consulta, lo que hace es transformar filas en columnas:
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('ifnull(SUM(case when vendedor=''',vendedor,''' then total end),0) AS `',vendedor, '`')) INTO @sql FROM ventaslistado;
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT fecha, ', @sql, ' FROM ventaslistado GROUP BY fecha');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

y el resultado de la consulta que tengo es este:

Quisiera transformar esa consulta en una vista, como es posible? o cambiar la consulta para que me genere la vista como la ultima imagen.
Muchas gracias

Según entiendo, no puedes hacer una vista que sea dinámica, tendrías que ejecutar tu procedimiento y luego generar una vista o actualizar una vista a partir de esta misma. Podría estar equivocado, asi que estaré al ojo de las respuestas acá.

y como podria ejecutar entonces esa consulta desde php?

Como dije, podrías probar a crear un procedimiento almacenado, que genere una vista que contenga los resultados del procedimiento. Luego, al momento de volver a llamar al procedimiento, vuelves a actualizar la vista, y esos serían tus datos actualizados.

si no es mucho pedir, como seria el procedimiento paso a paso? podrias incluir la consulta y demas? gracias

No es posible crear una vista sin una estructura de columnas definida.
En otras palabras: no puedes tener una vista cuya sentencia SQL no sea 100% conocida al momento de la creación de la vista y por tanto, no puedes crear una vista cuya estructura dependa de la generación y ejecución de SQL dinámico.
Esta no es una limitante de mySQL, probablemente de todos los motores de base de datos relacionales, pero al menos Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Firebird, DB2 y otros tienen la misma limitante.
Puedes, sin embargo, tener un procedimiento almacenado que haga el select. Si te conviene o no, depende de si tu lenguaje de alto nivel puede obtener el conjunto de resultados a partir de la ejecución del procedimiento almacenado.
Procedimiento Almacenado
Puedes crear un procedimiento que tenga el código que ya publicaste, por ejemplo:
DELIMITER !!
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE rp_resumen_ventas_fecha()
BEGIN
  SET @SQL = NULL;
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('ifnull(SUM(case when vendedor=''',vendedor,''' then total end),0) AS `',vendedor, '`')) INTO @sql FROM ventaslistado;
  SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT fecha, ', @sql, ' FROM ventaslistado GROUP BY fecha');
  PREPARE stmt1 FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt1;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
END!!
DELIMITER ;

Dentro de cualquier cliente de mySQL lo invocas así:
call rp_resumen_ventas_fecha();

Dejé un fiddle dónde puedes probarlo:

Es lo que yo pensaba, es posible convertir su consulta a procedimiento almacenado, y con esos resultados generar una vista sobre la cual pueda trabajar? y entonces cuando llame al procedimiento, actualizar nuevamente la vista?

No se puede crear una vista en base a un procedimiento almacenado.

pregunta, si yo quisiera hacer una consulta al procedimiento almacenado (seleccionar registros en un rango de fechas), como seria?

puedes agregar la fecha inicial y final como parámetros del procedimiento y usarlas dentro de la consulta.

lo siento, apenas y pude crear la consulta inicial no se como seria, podrias ayudarme poniendo el codigo? gracias por cierto no se que curso puedo tomar para aprender a hacer este tipo de cosas. Alguno que me recomiendes?

Considero que tu pregunta inicial está respondida. Si ahora tienes una nueva pregunta, te recomiendo investigar si hay alguna pregunta que cubra el tema y, si no encuentras nada útil, que hagas una nueva pregunta, tipo ¿cómo agregar parámetros de fechas a mi SP y tomarlos en cuenta en mi consulta dinámica? o algo así. No olvides publicar el código el SP como parte de la pregunta.

Sobre cursos, no sabría recomendar ninguno. Yo soy de leer libros y he aprendido de manera autodidacta, en parte, leyendo y, en parte, probando. Hasta la fecha, no recuerdo haber leído un libro de mySQL, motor que uso, pero poco. He leído muchos de otros motores, sin embargo.
